Why is map sort ideology less common?
Instead of doing a quicksort, you can store everything in a map. Because the map is alphabetical it's already sorted.
It seems like instead of doing a quicksort you could instantly put everything in a map and get it back as a o1 operation.
Why is quicksort done when you can just put everything in a map? The disadvantage is running out of memory but then you're implying the memory is somewhat of a fraud because you have more discrete values than the memory can store anyway.
Even so you can just layer the map to get the same result, if values crowd into one key then you can create a map under that key and it barely changes the complexity. There's no notation to express this but it would be o(1)(n/m) where n is the number of possible entries divided by the firmware limits of the memory to virtualize addresses.
The example function would be treemap.

Please use $f \in O(n)$ and $f \in o(n)$ as appropriate.

"because the map is alphabetical", who says?

For example, the built in functions in Java do this

please mention the example functions clearly in your question, and please clarify more on "firmware limits of the memory to virtualize address"

also clarify on what "layer the map" does, and how would it be done w.r.t the examples you provide

The example function would cover every demand.

The keys of the map are the values to be sorted, so if they're "crowded into one key" then they're equal, so you could use either a list or an integer count for the second, and final, layer. Unclear to me what memory virtualization has to do with that.

Inserting $n$ items into a sorted map takes a total of $O(n \log n)$ time, so the running time is not faster than sorting the $n$ items.

Similar story for a radix map (e.g. a trie) vs radix sort.

Isn't that the exact complexity of quick sort

@user1503883 It sure is! (At least on suitably random lists.) And lots of other sort algorithms besides. In fact, it's pretty easy to prove that O(n log(n)) is optimal for sorts that only use greater than/less than comparisons on the objects being sorted.

@user1503883 Two algorithms with the same BigO complexity do not necessarily have the same real performance, they just scale in the worst case at the same rate. There's also memory use to consider.

Apples vs Oranges
Quicksort is a sorting algorithm, whereas a map/dictionary/hashtable/hashmap is a container data structure. Use cases of both are widely apart.
As far as your argument is concerned, yes one can sort items that way, but depending on the input and map implementation, a map would need to perform much more operations like insertion, collision handling and resizing, all of which are not needed in sorting.
As far as TreeMap is concerned, it uses Red-Black trees underneath. So effectively and as rightly pointed out by @D.W.'s answer, the running time, or the time complexity, is not better.

How does quick sort not require insertion, and the memory also requires virtualization

@user1503883 You are again comparing Apples and Oranges by introducing virtual memory into this. Quicksort is much much more easy to implement and understand than RB tree or a balanced tree. The fact that YOU don't have to implement a sorted map doesn't mean it's free from cost. Just implement one and see for your self which is faster. It's pretty easy to see that a map implemented with a balanced tree still requires O(nlogn) to sort an array.


Instantly put everything in a map and get it back as a $O(1)$ operation.

HashMap operations do run in $O(1)$, but it cannot be used for sorting.
TreeMap can be used for sorting, but its operations run in $O(\log n)$.

The operations would be somewhat better than log n if mapped correctly. Because many of the operations are o(1).

@user1503883 Do you map with TreeMap, or something else?

Treemap or a c function using the memory. Because the memory location is read anyway the size of the map there can be anything and still be one read

@user1503883 Both c++ map and java TreeMap use Red-Black Tree, whose search, insertion, deletion runs in $O(\log n)$.

It's actually somewhat faster than log n because the leaf breadth can be arbitrary

@user1503883 It is still $O(\log n)$ even if you use B+ Tree which Wikipedia describes as having "very high fanout" of more than 100 children per nodes.

It's o1 if the nodes are single children and you're just iterating or reading a node.

@user1503883 reading is not the problem for the run time, inserting is. Yes you can iterate over trees in O(n), but you can also iterate over a sorted array in O(n).

Several reasons:

As the other answers have said, keeping the items sorted isn't fundamentally cheaper than sorting them when needed. It's only when you want to see the sorted result often that keeping it sorted may become worthwhile. But we may need to insert very often while looking at sorted results very rarely.
Often, we want different sort orders depending on which question we want to answer.
Often, we don't want to sort all items, but only a selection or aggregation of the items.

For instance, consider logs for a software system. Let's suppose we log users' actions, with a timestamp, the user, the name of the action, and maybe more.
We may want to query these logs in many different ways. For instance, maybe I want to see the top 10 users by number of actions. Or the top 10 hours by number of actions. Or the first and last recorded action for every user, sorted by the time difference between them. Or who knows what else. (Thousands of queries may be of interest. That's why SQL was invented.)
All of these example queries require sorting, but for none of them, it is helpful to keep the original log entries sorted in whatever way, because for each of them, it is far more efficient to first filter and aggregate the logs, and only then, sort the results, which must be done in a different order each time.
If certain of these queries will be posed very often (e.g. if their results are continually displayed in a dashboard), then it may definitely pay off to follow your proposal, and keep a sorted list of items (and/or a selected list of items, and/or an aggregated list of items). But we only want to do this for queries we know will be asked frequently. We don't want to do it for every conceivable query that may possibly come; that will be too expensive or impossible.
